# Linux: Why am I able to use ping if neither SETUID nor Capabilities are set?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl, ping, linux-capabilities

I thought that I'd grasped the basics of file permissions and capabilities.
But now - what's that?

**1. verify that there's no SETUID bit set:**

```
$ ll /bin/ping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72776 Jan 31 00:11 /bin/ping*
```

**2. verify that there're no capabilities set:**

```
$ getcap /bin/ping
/bin/ping =
```

**3. use ping**

```
$ /bin/ping google.com
PING google.com(qro01s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4012:80a::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from qro01s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4012:80a::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=418 ms
64 bytes from qro01s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4012:80a::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=120 time=102 ms
```

**4. verify that an raw socket is opened:**

```
$ strace -e socket ping google.com
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMPV6) = 4
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(AF_NETLINK, **SOCK_RAW**|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 5
```

**>> So why the heck is /bin/ping allowed or capable of opening a SOCK_RAW without SETUID nor cap_net_raw?**
NOTE: I'm of course not root trying that!
I'm using Linux Mint Ulyana.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating (normal) ICMP packets does not require special permissions anymore.  You can use

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMPV6) = 4
```

sockets (from your logs in 4).

The `SOCK_RAW` marked by you in

```
socket(AF_NETLINK, **SOCK_RAW**|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 5
```

is a NETLINK socket and used to check whether IPv6 can be used (call "ping" with "-4" or "-6" to see the difference).  These kind of sockets does not require special permissions either.

Comment: So ping in fact doesn't need neither privileges nor capabilites any more... Thank you, ensc!

Comment: Anymore since when? What kernel version or ping version introduced this change?

Comment: Could someone help me trace the linux version / commits to know more in depth?. I see question is ~4 years old. So may it is before v4.2 kernel release.

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer might not be correct, there is `net.ipv4.ping_group_range` which allows to construct the ICMP packets. Which was added around 3 years ago.

```
ping_group_range - 2 INTEGERS
    Restrict ICMP_PROTO datagram sockets to users in the group range.
    The default is "1 0", meaning, that nobody (not even root) may
    create ping sockets.  Setting it to "100 100" would grant permissions
    to the single group. "0 4294967295" would enable it for the world, "100
    4294967295" would enable it for the users, but not daemons.
```

source : [Linux Kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blame/0326074ff4652329f2a1a9c8685104576bd8d131/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst)

I found another nice answer [How does ping work on Fedora without setuid and capabilities?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592911/how-does-ping-work-on-fedora-without-setuid-and-capabilities) explaining in more details.

I addition to this, I did checked on my machine, which doesnt has the above param set, but the ping binary has the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability.

```
Linux ip-10.0.0.1 5.15.0-1022-aws #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 12:59:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
 getcap /usr/bin/ping
/usr/bin/ping cap_net_raw=ep
```

So we need some sort of mechanism for sure AFAIK , to open raw sockets.

If someone has more information, please chime in.